# Explode an longtext into array

Tags: php, arrays, explode, implode

I have longtext column in mysql db and want to expldoe it into array. But explode returns me only 1 string.

```
$temp_array_links[] = $item->links; //array value: http://google.com/ http://test.com/ http://test1.com/
$temp_string = implode(" ", $temp_array_links); //convert array to string
$info_array_links = explode(" ", $test_string); //explode string
echo 'Your link: <a href="'. $info_array_links[$user_id--] .'">LINK</a>'; //should be http://google.com/ insted of http://google.com/ http://test.com/ http://test1.com/
```

Comment: This is not a mysql question.

Comment: array(1) { [0]=> string(58) "http://google.com/ http://test.com/ http://test1.com/" }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the third line, you used the wrong variable name `$test_string`, you should have used `$temp_string`

Comment: oh, it's left after experiments, sorry, but problem doesn't solve

Comment: Sometimes its printed a white space character " ", but it is actually a "\n" character. Could you check that? Just replace the " " for "\n".

Answer (score 1):

your `$test_string` should be `$temp_string`  try

```
$temp_array_links = array('http://google.com/', 'http://test.com/', 'http://test1.com/');
echo $temp_string = implode(" ", $temp_array_links); //convert array to string
$info_array_links = explode(" ", $temp_string); //explode string
print_r($info_array_links);
```

Also for fetching array you need to use index of an array  not `$info_array_links[$user_id--]` try `$info_array_links[0] // 1, 2,3`

Comment: try print_r($temp_array_links) and show your result

Answer (score -1):

try to implode and explode with a separated something like **`;`**

```
    $temp_string = implode(";", $temp_array_links); //convert array to string
    $info_array_links = explode(";", $temp_string); //explode string
```

Comment: have you checked what is the string you are getting after implode?

Comment: i think its problem with variable name